# Зачем нужны значения аргументов по-умолчанию?

Tags: python

Где можно использовать аргументы по-умолчанию ? 
Где они вообще применяются ?

Comment: Аргументы по умолчанию в функциях?

Comment: да именно в функциях

Comment: Вы не поверите, но в самих функциях, а нужны для того, чтобы не постоянно не инициализировать некоторые параметры при вызове этой самой функции.

Comment: Они применяются там, где удобно задать какие-то значения по умолчанию ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Этот вопрос не вопроc, а тема для самостоятельного изучения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу простой пример:

```py
def fixed(number, digits=2):
    return f"{number:.{digits}f}"
```

Что делает эта функция? Возвращает строковое значение числа с фиксированным количеством знаков после запятой. Есть 3 основных способа вызова такой функции:

```py
fixed(123.456, 2) # Вызываем как обычную функцию и переопределяем аргумент digits
```

```py
fixed(123.456, digits=2) # Переопределяем аргумент digits, таким образом можно 
# менять порядок аргументов, если у нас несколько аргументов по умолчанию
```

```py
fixed(123.456) # Не передаем аргумент digits, и в функцию подставляется значение
# по умолчанию, равное двум.
```